# I have created a table named "option" through python, now how can I access or delete this table?

Tags: python, mysql

After I typed "DESCRIBE option", an error occurred: 
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'option' at line 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option is a reserved keyword.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html

But you can use backticks like this.

```
DESCRIBE `option`
```

To delete this table.

```
DELETE TABLE `option`
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
 connection = pymysql.connect("localhost", "user", "password", "database")
 cursor = connection.cursor()

 db_table = input("Table Name: ")
 show_table = "SELECT * FROM %s"%(db_table)
 cursor.execute(show_table)
 result = cursor.fetchall()

 for row in result:
 print("-----------------------------")
 print(row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4])
 print("-----------------------------")

 connection.commit()
 connection.close()
```